# Suspend after `HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo`

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm using SpringBoot and Hibernate, but the application stops after log `HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo` at start up.

What does it mean?

Full stack:

```
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.5.RELEASE)

2019-01-19 17:30:40.343  INFO 23942 --- [           main] com.mafengwo.Application                 : Starting Application on sunxingbindeMacBook-Pro.local with PID 23942 (/Users/sunxingbin/IdeaProjects/contentrepojob/target/classes started by sunxingbin in /Users/sunxingbin/IdeaProjects/contentrepojob)
2019-01-19 17:30:40.347  INFO 23942 --- [           main] com.mafengwo.Application                 : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-01-19 17:30:40.470  INFO 23942 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@cd3fee8: startup date [Sat Jan 19 17:30:40 CST 2019]; root of context hierarchy
2019-01-19 17:30:41.910  INFO 23942 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2019-01-19 17:30:42.208  INFO 23942 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$86296a04] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-01-19 17:30:42.750  INFO 23942 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 10086 (http)
2019-01-19 17:30:42.788  INFO 23942 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-01-19 17:30:42.788  INFO 23942 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.34
2019-01-19 17:30:42.801  INFO 23942 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/Users/sunxingbin/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.]
2019-01-19 17:30:43.028  INFO 23942 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-01-19 17:30:43.028  INFO 23942 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2561 ms
2019-01-19 17:30:43.130  INFO 23942 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2019-01-19 17:30:43.135  INFO 23942 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2019-01-19 17:30:43.136  INFO 23942 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2019-01-19 17:30:43.136  INFO 23942 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2019-01-19 17:30:43.137  INFO 23942 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2019-01-19 17:30:43.200  INFO 23942 --- [           main] o.s.j.d.DriverManagerDataSource          : Loaded JDBC driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
2019-01-19 17:30:43.402  INFO 23942 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-01-19 17:30:43.433  INFO 23942 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2019-01-19 17:30:43.549  INFO 23942 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.17.Final}
2019-01-19 17:30:43.550  INFO 23942 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2019-01-19 17:30:43.599  INFO 23942 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
Sat Jan 19 17:30:43 CST 2019 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
2019-01-19 17:30:44.423  INFO 23942 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Sat Jan 19 17:30:45 CST 2019 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
2019-01-19 17:30:45.251  INFO 23942 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-01-19 17:30:45.271  INFO 23942 --- [           main] o.s.j.d.DriverManagerDataSource          : Loaded JDBC driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
2019-01-19 17:30:45.276  INFO 23942 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-01-19 17:30:45.276  INFO 23942 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
```

Comment: For how long is it stuck and does it unstuck itself eventually? Could it be that you have one of these monolithic enterprise application with thousands of different `@Entity` classes?

Comment: @KarolDowbecki for several minutes. The database has hundreds tables but I only use 3 of them.